# Notifying POJO on collection item change

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-roo

I have a simple scenario (classes are simplified):

```
@Entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord( finders = {"findEventsByBeginTime"})
class Event{
    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("beginTime ASC")
    Set<EventStage> stages;

    Date beginTime;
    Date endTime;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
class EventStage{
    @ManyToOne
    Event parentEvent;

    Date beginTime;
    Date endTime;
}
```

I would like to update parent Event.beginTime and Event.endTime accorting to soonest and latest EventStage, whenever change is done to an EventStage.

Is there a way (Roo, Hibernate, Spring) to notify when item is being modified? It has to apply to adding new EventStage and deleting existing one. Of course I can approach it by some brute force checks but I'm looking for more sophisticated way.

Comment: Why make life unnecessarily difficult? If you add methods to add/remove `EventStage`s to `Event` and do not allow any other modifying access to the `stages` collection from outside you will always be able to update `beginTime` accordingly.

Comment: That is exactly my brute force solution :) but it doesnt resolve updating Event on EventStage update

Comment: Why you call it brute force? Imo it's simple and concise without depending on any framework tricks. Edit: OK, in your original post you said 'it has to apply to adding new EventStage and deleting existing one' and nothing about updating. In that case I would also add methods to update an `EventStage` to `Event`.

Comment: Perhaps an Observer? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl - of course I can use observers and go back to brute force solution of writting everything on my own. I was thinking rather about something that comes wrapped in Spring fancy stuff and is tested to work closer with whole entity management idea.

Comment: You can probably do it with an aspect using AspectJ.  But that sort of tool is more suited for when you have multiple classes that all need to do a similar thing (a cross-cutting concern).  Or for introducing behavior/members after the fact.

Comment: @tgharold in fact I started AJ approach. Even if i have only 1 pojo to work with this way it keeps my classes neat.

Comment: I think AJ is overkill.  There is no "Spring fancy way" because there is no need too have one.  I think you are overly complicating your code by using a sledgehammer to set a nail.  It's just my opinion, of coarse, but I think there are development patterns around, like the mentioned Observer pattern, that can be used.